# Deleting assets from watchOS app through code?

Tags: swift, watchkit

I'm working with a watchOS app and I'm creating a set-up screen with some videos to help introduce the user to the app. They will be added to the project directory alongside the app's .swift files.

These assets will take up a few megabytes and will never be presented to the user again, leading me to wonder if I can have code auto-delete them after the set-up sequence is completed.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot modify your app Bundle after the app has been built. All files that are part of your application's bundle are part of your app's signature as well, so modifying the bundle would actually break code signing.

If you want to be able to remove assets, they can't be part of the bundle. See [on demand resources](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/On_Demand_Resources_Guide/index.html) for a 1st party Apple solution on how to host assets remotely.